# C# sql How to get specific column's data to datagrid

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid

I want to get specific colums to show on my C# WPF DataGrid.

I used this code to get selected columns:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT roll FROM cmt_7th", con);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("cmt_7th");
    sda.Fill(dt);
    MydataGrid_roll.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
```

But I want to show only those row which column data is empty .

[image: Like this]

Left image is output screen short and right image is sql table image on "Like this" link image

I want to get rows 5 to 10 and ignore 1 to 4 row where all columns are not null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your description, you want to get all row where `name, department, phone` are `null`. So, you have to apply condition in your `sql`. Please check this:

```
string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT roll FROM cmt_7th WHERE name IS Null And department IS Null And phone IS Null", con);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("cmt_7th");
    sda.Fill(dt);
    MydataGrid_roll.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

}
```

Check this output of the SQL:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much... Will not I be your friends on facebook??
I am waiting , [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/sabbir.TT)

Comment: Hey

I need to determine that roll 5 rows is open. But how??

Comment: I'm little bit busy, I'll back soon.

Comment: @SabbirTT, what do you mean by "I need to determine that roll 5 rows is open."?

Comment: If you want to get only `roll no 5`, then use `Top 1` in sql. SQL: `SELECT Top 1 roll FROM cmt_7th WHERE name IS Null And department IS Null And phone IS Null`.

Comment: If you want to get `first 5 rows`, then use `Top 5` in sql. SQL: `SELECT Top 5 roll FROM cmt_7th WHERE name IS Null And department IS Null And phone IS Null`.

Comment: I want to determine that, my output sell is what?? or my output row number is what?

Comment: You can get number of records by using 'dt.Rows.Count' from C#.